# Как задать аргументам функции значения инпутов?

Tags: javascript, dom

Всем привет! Есть задача в которой надо создавать календарь по текущей дате. Реализация есть:

```js
let inputYear = document.getElementById('year');
let inputMonth = document.getElementById('month');
let showDesiredDateButton = document.getElementById('#button');

showDesiredDateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  createTable(inputYear, inputMonth);
  fillTableTd(getAllDatesInMonth(inputYear, inputMonth));
  hideEmptyCells();
});
```

```html
<div id="input-date">
  <input id="year" placeholder="Year" type="text">
  <input id="month" placeholder="Month" type="text">
  <button id="button">Показ Даты</button>
</div>
```

Но, так не работает - выдает *ObjectInputElement*.

А, если вызвать функции так, как ниже, то всё работает как надо:

```
  createTable(2020,3);
  fillTableTd(getAllDatesInMonth(2020,3));
  hideEmptyCells();
```

Я новичок в программировании. Помогите, если есть идеи и, желательно, как можно по-простому.

Comment: Сделайте `inputYear.value`

Comment: В inputYear и inputMonth у вас находятся инпуты как элементы DOM, а не их значения.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setArg(y, m) {
  console.log(y, m)
}


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  setArg(year.value, month.value);
});
```

```html
<div id="input-date">
  <input id="year" placeholder="Year" type="text">
  <input id="month" placeholder="Month" type="text">
  <button id="btn">Показ Даты</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Кто такие `year.setAttribute` и `month.setAttribute`?

Comment: @Quazimorda, это я не верно понял вопрос и добавлял атрибуты `input-AM`