# Как применить transform к тексту внутри кнопки?

Tags: css3, html5

Есть такая кнопка для входа на сайт:

```css
.auth-button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #5b88bd;
  border: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 14px 0;
  outline: none;
}

.auth-button:active {
  background-color: #4a76a8;
}

.auth-button-span:active {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```

```html
<button class="auth-button"><span class="auth-button-span">Войти</span></button>
```

Как можно сделать `transform` по вертикали на 5px для текста `Войти`? Я так думаю тут дело связано с `position`. И возможно ли это сделать без `span` внутри `button`?

Comment: уже был подобный вопрос... при чем тут значение инпутов, и трансформ.....?))))))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать аргументам функции значения инпутов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093376/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @Air вопросы по-существу - разные. Автор тот же и похоже с заголовком напутал, но это не дубликат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что дополнительный тег `<span>` нужен лишь для разделения классов и более тонкой и гибкой настройки стилей. Ведь "голубая кнопка" и "белые буквы" звучит проще и логичнее, чем "голубая кнопка с белым текстом". Особенно такое критично, если подразумевается поддержка, например, "ночных" или кастомных тем оформления. Т.ч. можно  обойтись и без `<span>`, если не требуется вышеизложенное.

Не совсем понял, для чего `transform: translate()`?.. Я вижу решение так (вторая кнопка без `<span>`, но эффект тот же):

```css
.auth-button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #5b88bd;
  border: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 14px 0;
  outline: none;
}

.auth-button:active {
  background-color: #4a76a8;
  /* Сдвиг вверх */
  padding: 0 0 5px;
  /* Сдвиг вниз
  padding: 5px 0 0; */
}
```

```html
<button class="auth-button"><span class="auth-button-span">Войти</span></button>
<br>
<button class="auth-button">Войти</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно сделать transform по вертикали на 5px для текста Войти? И
>   возможно ли это сделать без span внутри button?

Только средствами CSS невозможно. По крайней мере, мне такое свойство неизвестно, чтобы можно было увеличить только высоту текста, не увеличивая его размер. Но можно поступить хитро, без использования `span` внутри `button`, использовать псевдоэлемент `:before`. Вот пример:

```css
.auth-button {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #5b88bd;
  border: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 14px 0;
  outline: none;
}

.auth-button:before {
  content: "Войти";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 2.4;
}

.auth-button:active {
  background-color: #4a76a8;
}

.auth-button:active:before {
  transform: scale(1, 1.4);
}
```

```html
<button class="auth-button"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Span выбран наверное не очень удачно, ибо это изначально инлайновый элемент. Чтобы сработало - пропишите ему `display: block;`
2. Псевдокласс `:active` относится скорее к самой кнопке, поэтому я попробовал бы так:

```css
    .auth-button {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 35px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #5b88bd;
        border: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 14px 0;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    .auth-button:active {
        background-color: #4a76a8;
    }
    
    .auth-button:active span {
        display: block;
        transform: translate(0, 5px);
     }
```

```html
    <button class="auth-button"><span class="auth-button-span">Войти</span></button>
```

Спозициорировать сдвиг сможете более красиво. А если собирались не сдвигать, а растягивать, то нужно использовать `scale` вместо `translate`.